# How to create a word by juxtaposing a noun with a description, where the description consists of two words?

Tags: word-choice

I want to write in my CV that I'm good at detecting errors, I want to humourously write that I'm an "error-detector-man". Is it correct to write it like this? "Error detector" alone is correct, but sounds like a name of a machine.

Comment: Once a debugger, Always a Debugger! ( thinking emoji)

Comment: @Cardinal In fact, "debugger" would be a nice word to use in this context. Something like "debugger mentality"... Thank you for an idea.

Comment: What kind of "error" are we talking about? Grammatical errors? or ...

Comment: I mean errors which can occur at work: mistakes in processes, gaps in thought processes, errors in programming codes...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write in my CV

Usually a CV or resume should have a professional tone, rather than a comedic one. Notice how people write on the website Linkedin.

You could say the same thing but not as a joke.

> conscientious

or

> a very conscientious employee, who can assist (your company) in correcting mistakes in processes, gaps in thought processes, errors in programming codes.

---

Changing the subject away from CV's, and towards standard English:

"error-detector-man" might be written as "Error-Detector-Man" (like Spider-Man).

To a native English speaker, this comes across as sort of childish humor, rather than a sophisticated joke.

Something I have thought about before is that you can sometimes judge your own fluency, or someone else's fluency in a language, by mastery of the non-standard forms of language: not ordinary prose, but comedy and poetry. You might be cautious about publication of comedy or poetry until they have reached a very good level of fluency.

Answer (score -1):

You could use phrases like, "have an eye for details, strict in following laid down processes and protocols, or with eyes that detect flaws quickly" etc.